# Why receive weird error messages asp.net mvc "elmah.mvc logging library"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, elmah, elmah.mvc

I have web application developed using Asp.Net MVC 5.

I am integrated [Elmah.MVC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elmah.MVC/) error logging library for error logging and reporting.

I got weird error messages
like the following:

```
System.Web.HttpException: The controller for path '/manager/html' was not found or does not implement IController.
```

The source of request was the following ip `221.194.44.229`
which is in China.

Another message:

```
System.Web.HttpException: The controller for path '/888/pakistani-hackers-forcing-pilots-listen-pakistan-kashmir' was not found or does not implement IController.
```

The source of request was the following ip `39.45.204.204`
which is in Pakistan.

I do not know if elmah.mvc is contains malware or such trojan or myserver was hacked how to investigate that issue  and where is problems come from.

Do not know if that the correct place to ask such question or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mainly there is some one trying to request apath that is not on your site.

The idia is to make you read the massage in the requested path ( like the secound error from your post) that is som kind of spam.

There is nothing to worry about? This happened every day.

But i  think you need to enable custom error pages if you are not already do.

Comment: i am afraid that is kind of DOS attack i can not identify it

Comment: That debends of the ammount and frequency of the requests.

Comment: And DOS attacks mainly request an existing path to make your site do more work.